# Ayuda el valor de la cantidad se me almacena para todo los stock?

Tags: php, jquery

Estoy haciendo un carrito de compra via web ya esta practicamente terminado el problema que al verificar que la cantidad es igual al stock este me arroja un mensaje diciendo excedio el limite, pero eso sucede con todo los que tienen el mismo stock que otra opción me recomiendan.

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){



$('.btcar').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.isPropagationStopped();
    var car = $(this).attr("id");
    var stock = parseInt ($('#stock'+car).val());
    var cant = parseInt($('#canti'+car).val());




    if(stock != cant ){

    $.ajax({

        url:'carrito.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data:{car:car},
        type:JSON,
        success:function(deta){

            $('#carrito').html(deta);
            $('#resultado').html(deta);
        }

    });

 } else{

     alert("Excedió el límite");

 }});  


$('#carrito').load("carrito.php");


    });
</script>
```

-- este es el del carrito

```
<article>
            <?php 
    if(isset ($_SESSION['usuario1'])){


    ?>
            <!-----ARREGLO MULTIDIMENCIONAL------>
            <?php
       if(isset($_POST['car'])){
       $id= $_POST['car'];
       $cantidad=1;
       $sql3="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = '$id'";
       $query3= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql3);
       $row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3);

       $id= $row3['id'];
                $imagen= $row3['imagen'];
                $nombre= $row3['nombre'];
                $descripcion= $row3['descripcion'];
                $precio= $row3['precio'];
                $stock= $row3['stock'];
                $fecha= $row3['fecha'];
                $hora= $row3['hora'];
                $categoria=$row3['categoria'];
       $sucursal=$row3['sucursal'];
                $cantidad;


     $shopCart[]= array('id'=> $id,'imagen'=> $imagen,'nombre'=>   $nombre,'descripcion'=> $descripcion,'precio'=> $precio, 'stock'=> $stock, 'fecha'=> $fecha, 'hora'=> $hora, 'categoria'=> $categoria, 'sucursal'=> $sucursal, 'cantidad'=> $cantidad);

   }       

        if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
           $shopCart = $_SESSION['carrito'];
            if(isset($_POST['car'])){

                 $sql3="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = '$id'";
       $query3=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql3);
       $row3= mysqli_fetch_array($query3);


               $id= $row3['id'];
                $imagen= $row3['imagen'];
                $nombre= $row3['nombre'];
                $descripcion= $row3['descripcion'];
                $precio= $row3['precio'];
                $stock= $row3['stock'];
                $fecha= $row3['fecha'];
                $hora= $row3['hora'];
                $categoria=$row3['categoria'];
                $sucursal=$row3['sucursal'];
                $cantidad;
                $posicion = -1;   


            for($i=0; $i<count($shopCart);$i++){
                if($id == $shopCart[$i]['id']){
                    $posicion = $i;  
                }
                          }  

                if($posicion != -1){
                    $cantidad_nueva = $shopCart[$posicion]['cantidad'] + $cantidad;
                    $shopCart[$posicion] = array('id'=> $id,'imagen'=> $imagen,'nombre'=> $nombre,'descripcion'=> $descripcion,'precio'=> $precio, 'stock'=> $stock, 'fecha'=> $fecha, 'hora'=>$hora, 'categoria'=> $categoria, 'sucursal'=> $sucursal, 'cantidad'=> $cantidad_nueva);

                }else{
                    $shopCart[]= array('id'=> $id,'imagen'=> $imagen,'nombre'=> $nombre,'descripcion'=> $descripcion,'precio'=> $precio, 'stock'=> $stock, 'fecha'=> $fecha, 'hora'=>$hora, 'categoria'=> $categoria, 'sucursal'=> $sucursal, 'cantidad'=> $cantidad);

                }

            }
        }

        // NUEVOS PROCESOS...

        // PROCESO PARA ACTUALIZAR PRODUCTO

    if(isset($_POST['idupdate'])){

      $idupdate= $_POST['idupdate'];
      $cantidad= $_POST['cantidad'];
      $shopCart[$idupdate]['cantidad']= $cantidad;
  }      



        // Proceso para eliminar productos

        if(isset($_POST['ideliminar'])){
            $ideliminar= $_POST['ideliminar'];
      $shopCart[$ideliminar] = NULL;


        }

        if(isset($shopCart)){

            $_SESSION['carrito'] = $shopCart;
        }



?>

                <table class="table">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th class="th"></th>
                            <th class="th">Imagen</th>
                            <th class="th">Nombre</th>
                            <th class="th">Precio</th>
                            <th class="th">Cantidad</th>
                            <th class="th">Subtotal</th>
                            <th></th>&nbsp;</tr>
                    </thead>


                           <tbody >
                            <?php 
         if(isset($shopCart)){
             $total = 0;
             for($i=0; $i<count($shopCart); $i++){

             if($shopCart[$i] != NULL){

          ?> 
                           <tr >

                           <td>  <?php echo $shopCart[$i]['sucursal'] ?> </td>
                            <td><img src="img/productos/<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['imagen'] ?>" width="150" height="150"></td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $shopCart[$i]['nombre'] ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo number_format ( $shopCart[$i]['precio'], 0, '', '.'); ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                                <form method="post" id="formstock">
                                     <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock']; ?>">

                                </form>


                                <form method="post" class="formcantidad" >

                                   <input type="hidden" id="prue" value="<?php echo $i ?>">
                                    <input type="text" class="canti" id="canti<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock'] ?>" name="cantidad" min="1" maxlength="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock']; ?>" value="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['cantidad']; ?>" style="text-alaing: center;">

                                    <br>
                                </form>



                            </td>

                            <!------------- aqui guardan los calculos de los precios--->
                            <td>
                                <?php 
             $subtotal = $shopCart[$i]['precio']*$shopCart[$i]['cantidad'];
                 $total=$subtotal+$total;
                 echo 'Bs.S '; echo number_format ($subtotal, 0, '', '.');

             ?>
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                <form >
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ideliminar" value="<?php echo $i;?>">
                                    <button type="button" class="eliminarbt" id="<?php echo $i;?>"> <span class="fa fa-times" value="Eliminar" src="#" style="color:red; cursor:pointer;"> </span> </button>
                               </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php }}} ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="4"> &nbsp;


                            </td>

                            <td class="resultado"> <strong>Total </strong><br> Bs.S:
                             <?php echo @number_format ($total, 0, '', '.'); ?>   <br>


                                    <input type="hidden" id="total" name="total" value="<?php echo  @$total ; ?>">
                                    <button type="button" class="btsiguiente" src="#" style="width: 135px; height:40px;" value="Comprar"> <span class="fa fa-check" style="color:green; cursor:pointer;"> Siguiente</span></button>




                            </td>


                        </tr>

                    </tbody>



                </table>
                <br><br>
                <br>






                <?php

    }



            else{

        echo '<script>

        alert("Debes Iniciar Sesion Para Poder Realizar Esta Transicción");
        window.location.href="valencia-tocuyito.html";

        </script>';

    }

    ?>
        </article>
```

Comment: Podrias formular mejor tu pregunta y agregar el codigo de carrito.php por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
<input type="text" class="canti" id="canti<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock'] ?>" name="cantidad" min="1" maxlength="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock']; ?>" value="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['cantidad']; ?>" style="text-alaing: center;">
```

Estas asignando el valor de stock al id.  Si dos productos tienen la misma cantidad en stock entonces los dos te van a generar el mensaje.  En lugar de usar stock, usa la variable `$i` asi:

```
<input type="text" class="canti" id="canti<?php echo $i ?>" name="cantidad" min="1" maxlength="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['stock']; ?>" value="<?php echo $shopCart[$i]['cantidad']; ?>" style="text-alaing: center;">
```

Comment: amigo, gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder. Intente lo que ud me dijo pero nada, tome el mismo id por que con un boton me actualiza la tabla y me recoje el stock de while que estoy agarrando en la muestra del html por eso tome el mismo valor